# Set ipv6 addres/gateway with cloud-init

Tags: cloud-init

In CentOS 7.3 I had the following in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=[address]/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=[gateway address]
```

This worked fine. However, now that 7.4 uses cloud-init this gets reset on boot.

I can add the `IPV6INIT=yes` line by following the answer here:

[How do I enable IPv6 in RHEL 7.4 on Amazon EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/866696/how-do-i-enable-ipv6-in-rhel-7-4-on-amazon-ec2/934405#934405)

```
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-custom-networking.cfg
network:
  version: 1
  config:
  - type: physical
    name: eth0
    subnets:
      - type: dhcp6
```

This seems to work and enable IPV6 but it only works with DHCP. (Though I am not sure this is really being used as it doesn't seem to have any effect).

I also tried:

```
network:
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: physical
      name: eth0
      subnets
        - type: dhcp
        - type: static6
          address: [address]/64
          gateway: [gateway]
```

Though it doesn't make any changes in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

How do I set the equivalent of IPV6ADDR and IPV6_DEFAULTGW using cloud-init?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error with various examples, the following works:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp: true
            dhcp6: false
            match:
              name: eth0
            addresses:
              - "[address]"
            gateway6: "[gateway address]"
```